# Wait for the processing of geometries to be finished in OpenLayer.js

Tags: openlayers, async

I need to transform an array of geometries to [vector Layers](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_layer_Vector-VectorLayer.html) in [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org).

Here is a simple snippet of initial code:

```
var inputFeatureArray = [geom1, geom2, geom3, geom4, ...]
// I need to populate a second one with new ol.vector.layer
// from the geometries of the first array:
var array2 = []; 

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geom1,{
            dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
            featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
    }),
    projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});

var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource,
    zIndex: 1,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)',
            width: 2
        })
    }),
});
```

I was struggling a little before coming to this solution, which sounds good, but is obviously not working.
I have the feeling that the JS code doesn't wait for the second array to be actually filled...

```
var inputFeatureArray = [geom1, geom2, geom3, geom4, ...]

function processFeatures(inputArray) {
    let outputArray = [];
    for (feat of inputArray) {
        var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            // This may take some time...:
            features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(feat,{
                    dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
                    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
            }),
            projection: 'EPSG:3857'
        });
        var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource,
            zIndex: 1,
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'rgba(71, 248, 255, 0.9)',
                    width: 2
                }),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(71, 248, 255, 0.2)',
                }),
            }),
        });
        outputArray.push(vectorLayer);
    }
    return outputArray;
}

// Actual call to the function:
var array2 = processFeatures(inputFeatureArray);
console.log("array2: ", array2); // To see what's happening
```

There is actually no error, but the `console.log()` is showing empty stuff in my browser:

[image: Empty results]

I don't know how to tell that piece of code to wait for the 2nd array to be actually filled (if that is the problem of course).

In the end, I want to inject all the vector layers into a map:

```
// Here are the vectors layers in addition to one WMS basemap:
var layers = [tileLayer, array2];

var map = new ol.Map({
    controls: ol.control.defaults().extend([
        new ol.control.ScaleLine({
            units: 'degrees',
        })
    ]),
    layers: layers, // <-- layers plugged here
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        center: ol.proj.transform(
            location.coordinates.slice(0,2), 
            'EPSG:4326',
            'EPSG:3857'
        ),
        zoom: 8,
    }),
});
```

Comment: Are you sure your array2 is empty? I see four elements. Where definitely is a problem is your declaration `var layers = [ tileLayer, array2 ]`. Since `array2` is an array, OL will definitely protest with an error. It should be `var layers = [tileLayer].concat(array2)`.

Comment: Oh, so... these 'guys' in my console are actually four vector layers? It's not really explicit... But by exploring the objects more in details, I can read out some extent values, an opacity, and other things that make sense for a vector layer, indeed. And you were right on the `.concat()` method! So the mistake was here, not in my previous code where I was searching for hours (...), now the N-geometries are properly drawn, if you want to make an answer with sufficient explanations from your comment I would happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures` is not async. If you look at your console log, you'll see there are actually four elements in the `array2`. If you would expand them, you would see they are OK.

The actual problem is in your assignment `var layers = [tileLayer, array2]` and then using `layers` as map `layers` option. This options expects an array of layers, but the second element of your `layers` array is an array in itself, and so OL will definitely protest with an error.

In your definition of `layers` you should insert `tileLayer` element at the start of the `array2` array. One way to do this is:

```
var layers = [tileLayer].concat(array2);
```